# Surface integral of a sphere via definition

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, divergence-theorem

I attempted to calculate the surface integral $\iint_S F \cdot n \ dS$ where $F = (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)(x, y, z)$ and $S$ is the sphere of radius $a$ centered at the origin. I used the divergence theorem to obtain the result, but it doesn't coincide with the result I obtain via the definition of the surface integral and I cannot find my mistake.

Clearly $\nabla \cdot F = 5(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)$, so by doing a change to spherical coordinates we get
\begin{align*}
\iint_S F \cdot n \ dS &= \iiint_{x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = a^2} 5(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) \ dV \\
&= \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\pi \int_0^a 5a^2\rho^2 \sin \phi \ d\rho d\phi d\theta \\
&= 5a^2 \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\pi \frac{a^3}{3} \sin \phi \ d\phi d\theta \\
&= \frac{10}{3} \pi a^5 \int_0^\pi \sin \phi \ d\phi \\
&= \frac{20}{3} \pi a^5.
\end{align*}

Now, let's use the definition directly to compute the surface integral.

First, let's parametrize the sphere via spherical coordinates:

$$x = a \sin \phi \cos \theta, \quad y = a \sin \phi \sin \theta, \quad z = a \cos \phi.$$

So, our vector field, in this parametrization is equal to:

$$F = a^3(\sin \phi \cos \theta, sin \phi \sin \theta, \cos \phi).$$

And an outward pointing normal vector field is given by:

$$n = a^2 (\sin^2 \phi \cos \theta, \sin^2 \phi \sin \theta, \cos \phi \sin \phi).$$

By definition, the integrand of the double integral is the dot product of the previous two quantities:

$$F \cdot n = a^5 (\sin^3 \phi \cos^2 \theta + \sin^3 \phi \sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \phi \sin \phi) = a^5 \sin \phi.$$

So, our surface integral is:

$$\iint_S F \cdot n \ dS = \int_0^\pi \int_0^{2\pi} a^5 \sin \phi \ d\theta d\phi = 2\pi a^5 \int_0^\pi \sin \phi \ d \phi = 4\pi a^5.$$

The results are not the same, and I cannot find my mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the second line of your first string of equations you should have $5\rho^4 \sin(\phi)$ as your integrand instead of  $5a^2\rho^2 \sin(\phi)$. The domain of your triple integral should have $\leq a$ and not $=a$

Comment: You could also evaluate the flux integral without parameterizing the sphere $\rho=a$ by realizing that $\vec{n}=\frac{(x,y,z)}{a}$.

Comment: You're right! Thanks a lot.